# Prevent Chrome from setting scrollbar position to last on history state change

Tags: html, google-chrome, history.js

I used https://github.com/browserstate/history.js in a recent project to manage state changes in an ajax rich website.

Chrome exhibits a very annoying behaviour at times where it decides to reposition the scrollbar to some arbitrary position after a state change event. I have not experienced this problem with any other browser.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I would post code, but am not sure which parts will be relevant and I am hoping there is an obvious solution to this problem.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue, thinking it might be related to the popstate event

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious workarounds. Scroll to the top if that's what you want, or add a field to data object to store scroll position and restore it yourself. If it's a Chrome bug, work around it; if it's a feature you don't like, work around it; and if it's something you just have to implement yourself with three lines of code, work around it.

Comment: The problem is that Chrome exhibits this behaviour after other calls to `scrollTop` have been made. I "solved" it by using a combination of hacky absolute positioning and `setTimeout` callbacks to make it appear as though the scrollbar hadn't moved at all.

Comment: Bizarre. Sorry for junk answer then.

Comment: Not a junk answer, just a strange problem. I'm going to write some minimal html and javascript that demonstrates the issue.